# Any way to force change an Android device screenshot folder location / destination?

Tags: adb, samsung, file-system, screenshots

Is there any way to force an Android device to change it's screenshots file folder / destination location?

- Like ADB command or something?
- Something that is native and permanent?
- Something that isn't app based (I don't like PinSync and FolderSync as those are battery hogs too)

Specifically for my Samsung Android device. [Samsung infamously](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/12/30/dear-samsung-please-let-me-exclude-screenshots-from-google-photos-backups/) add their Screenshots folder inside `DCIM > Screenshots`, instead of what supposed to be in `Pictures > Screenshots` on virtually all their Android devices ever shipped. **Despite users asking for this change**, the problem still exist today.

I don't like this experience because of these such experiences :

- Photo Backup services like Google Photos or OneDrive auto backups your Screenshots too.
- I believe Screenshots in the cloud should be a manual backup. Not all of them are so important to be wasting your cloud storage
- Especially if your device has the Volume button on the right side, and Power on the left side, which makes accidentally screenshotting very easy.
- Literally your Photo Roll will be littered by accidental screenshots.

Some OEMs Android OS have their manual Screenshot folder location changing on their Settings apps, but not Samsung's One UI. And apps such as Google Photos doesn't support specific folder syncing yet. They only annoyingly support parent folders for now.

But if possible, I'm asking for a universal solution to this. That will work to any device / OEM. I don't like rooting, but if that's the only solution you know of, please tell me.

**I'm sick and tired of this. Please help me.**

Comment: You could use this to [sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) the folder to copy the contents to another folder and delete at source. You could use an automation app to run this every half hour or on pressing volume /power buttons (if that works for you)

Comment: Unless the location is stored as a configuration in a file/DB/anythine else, it probably needs root access to really force-move the location (instead of copying/syncing), since the location is possibly baked into the system when the OS is built.

Comment: @beeshyams Sorry man, but I just said I don't wanna use PinSync. As those apps usually gets shut down on Battery restrictions of each OEMs. As well as automation apps. Not native as well. Google Photos backup process is usually real time, so before they get moved to another folder, they're already backed up.

Comment: @AndrewT. I see. Do you have any knowledge where this configuration might be? Rooted or not rooted? 

And I indeed needed to be rooted, how can I do it? 

If you do not know, do you any places where it might be useful to ask help to modify these?

Comment: Possibly an app built on `inotify` API, running continuously a foreground service to watch filesystem changes. Or if the OEM's battery optimization is aggressive enough to kill even foreground services, then the same API using root. E.g. `busybox inotifyd`. That won't be killed for sure.

Comment: The screenshot save directory is hard coded in AOSP source code: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/a4ddee215e41ea232340c14ef92d6e9f290e5174/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/screenshot/GlobalScreenshot.java#L348-L349